# PactNet - the type or namespace name 'PactVerifierConfig' could not be found

Tags: .net, pact, pact-net

I'm trying to write a PactNet Provider test for my dotnet 7 web api.
I've installed the nuget package PactNet into my test proj and I see I have version 4.5 installed:

```
    <PackageReference Include="PactNet" Version="4.5.0" />
```

I've added the using statement on my test:

```
using PactNet;
```

but when I try to instantiate the config it says the class can't be found:

```
        var config = new PactVerifierConfig();

        IPactVerifier pactVerifier = new PactVerifier(config);
```

I've already tried the following:

Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Removed and re-added the PactNet nuget package.
Restarting VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add the following using statement:

```
using PactNet.Verifier;
```